# How to assign the variable value to radio button's value in php

Tags: php, html

Hi i am trying to assign the php variable value to the radio button's value

Here is what i am doing. But i am not able to see any value when i am alerting the value through java-script.

code:

```
  echo "<td class='ad'>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"; 
  echo '<input type="radio" name="address" value='$row['address']'/>';
```

i want to assign the `$row['address'] value to input value`=

how can i do this?

Comment: `echo '<input type="radio" name="address" value=' . $row['address']' . '/>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it right in the 1st line, while the 3rd should be like this:

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="address" value="' . $row['address'] . '"/>';
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the in-php echo (you're out of php code), you can write this:

> < input name="address" type="radio" value="< ?= $row['address']; ? >
>   Hope to be useful. I added some spaces to make my answer ok

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use `.` which is the string concatenation operator in php. what you have done is almost correct but you have not concatenated the string value with the php variable properly.

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="address" value=' . $row['address'] . '/>';
```